How to perform remote transfer on a pure proxy account using xcm
Alice is a pure proxy account (keyless account) created on Kusama Relay Chain.
Bob accidentally deposited DOT to Alice's address on Polkadot Relay Chain.
Can Alice's controller craft an XCM call on Kusama Relay Chain to remotely transfer the DOT on Polkadot Relay Chain back to Bob's address on Polkadot Relay Chain?
If so, could anyone provide more details on how that xcm call would look like?
And if not, are there any solution to retrieve the DOTs in Alice's address on Polkadot Relay Chain?
